# (R) how to get rolling join with grouped data

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to join two dataframes (df, df2) into one. Both datasets have a date column - I want to keep df's rows and add in the other cells of the df2 row with the closest date (that is not later than the date) of each df row. I've already figured out how to do this with a rolling join like in the code below.

However, I'm currently trying to figure out how I can also do the rolling join by group so that the df1 row is only matched with the df2 row with the closest date and the same group as the current df row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

x <- c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13)
y <- c(20, 30, 52, 14, 21, 42, 22, 65, 33, 35, 55, 56, 23, 43, 29, 33)
dates <- as.Date("2019-08-15") + c(0:15)
dates2 <- as.Date("2019-08-01") + c(0:15)

group <- c(rep(as.character('A'), 5), rep(as.character('B'), 4), rep(as.character('C'), 1), rep(as.character('D'), 6))

df <- data.frame(group, x, dates) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(group))

df2 <- data.frame(group, y, dates2) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(dates = dates2) %>%
  select(-dates2)

setDT(df)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df, dates)
setkey(df2, dates)

df2[df, roll = Inf]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually easily solved by

```
setkey(df, group dates)
setkey(df2, group, dates)
```

but I'll leave this up in case it's wrong or someone knows a better solution